# Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::update(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, stdClass given,

Tags: php, laravel

How can I convert stdClass to Array to update my DB in Laravel?

```
 $currentSubscriptionTransaction = new stdClass();
```

```
$subscription_transaction_to_update = DB::table('subscription_transactions')->where('id', $currentSubscriptionTransaction->id)->first();

            if (!is_null($subscription_transaction_to_update)) {
                DB::table('subscription_transactions')->where('id', $currentSubscriptionTransaction->id)->update(
                    ($currentSubscriptionTransaction)
                );
            }
```

I tried
`array($currentSubscriptionTransaction)`
but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try (array)$currentSubscriptionTransaction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$subscription_transaction_to_update = DB::table('subscription_transactions')->where('id', $currentSubscriptionTransaction->id)->first();

            if (!is_null($subscription_transaction_to_update)) {
                DB::table('subscription_transactions')->where('id', $currentSubscriptionTransaction->id)->update(
                    ($currentSubscriptionTransaction->toArray()) // this has to be an array
                );
}
```

A cleaner way of doing the same by using `Eloquent Model`

```
SubscriptionTransaction::firstOrCreate($currentSubscriptionTransaction->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

humm...
Maybe, you should better use some `helper functions` like `collect()` and  `toArray()` ?
see https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/en/helpers.html if your laravel version is 5.7

Laravel supply some useful methods or tips belong with your laravel app version.

For example if you use a DB table , this framework has model.php like `SubscriptionTransactions` under `Models/`
So,Can you try these code under following?

```
use App\Models\SubscriptionTransaction;
    $subscriptionTransactionToUpdate = SubscriptionTransaction::firstWhere('id', $currentSubscriptionTransaction->id);

    if ($subscriptionTransactionToUpdate) {
        $currentSubscriptionTransaction = new stdClass();
        $subscriptionTransactionToUpdate->update(collect($currentSubscriptionTransaction)->toArray());
    }
```